# Windows 10 bug when removing a shortcut from the toolbar

Tags: windows, windows-10

I accidentally removed firefox from my toolbar, but it still is there, kinda invisible. If I reattatch it, there pops up a new firefox and the blank space is still there. It works like the firefox shortcut, just no icon. How can I remove it?

Comment: Are you referring to Firefox icon in the Taskbar? What happens when you right-click on the icon and choose `Unpin from taskbar`?

Comment: the icon dissapears, but it remains there with all functionality. Firefox icon in the bar that is(normally) at the bottom of the screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pinned taskbar icons (shortcuts) are stored in one of these folders:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar
```

Open the above folders (paste the paths in Explorer Address bar) and delete the Firefox shortcut from there. Logoff and login back.

If that doesn't help, use the script here to [reset the taskbar](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-taskbar-settings-to-defaults/) to default configuration. Note that you'll need to Pin them all again manually.

Comment: YW. Which one worked?

Comment: The one at the top